# Installing ancient perls with Perlbrew

Tags: perl, perlbrew

I'm trying to use `perlbrew` to install some older Perls. I believe it's failing due to the old-style version numbers. According to `perlbrew available`:

```
  perl-5.14.3-RC1
  perl-5.16.1
  perl-5.14.2
  perl-5.12.4
  perl-5.10.1
  perl-5.8.9
  perl-5.6.2
  perl5.005_04
  perl5.004_05
  perl5.003_07
```

However, when I run `perlbrew install perl5.003_07`, I get:

```
 Unknown installation target "perl5.003_07", abort. Please see
 `perlbrew help` for the instruction on using the install command.
```

If I try it by giving a direct link to the tarball, e.g. `perlbrew install http://www.cpan.org/src/5.0/perl5.005_03.tar.gz`, it downloads the tarball but the regex for parsing the version number fails:

```
Use of uninitialized value $dist_version in concatenation (.) or string at /usr/local/share/perl5/App/perlbrew.pm line 686.
Fetching perl- as /home/cpanci/perl5/perlbrew/dists/perl5.005_03.tar.gz
Use of uninitialized value $dist_version in pattern match (m//) at /usr/local/share/perl5/App/perlbrew.pm line 925.
Installing /home/cpanci/perl5/perlbrew/build/perl5.005_03 into ~/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-

This could take a while. You can run the following command on another shell to track the status:

  tail -f ~/perl5/perlbrew/build.perl-.log

Use of uninitialized value $dist_version in pattern match (m//) at /usr/local/share/perl5/App/perlbrew.pm line 952.
Use of uninitialized value $dist_version in pattern match (m//) at /usr/local/share/perl5/App/perlbrew.pm line 969.

Installing /home/cpanci/perl5/perlbrew/build/perl5.005_03 failed. Read /home/cpanci/perl5/perlbrew/build.perl-.log to spot any
issues.
```

Any ideas? It's working fine for newer perls.

This is with App::perlbrew version 0.52.

Comment: Does using `--as perl-5.003_07` help?

Comment: `--as` does not help; it looks like it runs the version number regex on the original URL and not the `--as` parameter (which makes sense.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're stuck having to hack on perlbrew.  I can get some ways by renaming the tarball `perl-5.5.3.tar.gz` and making a symlink in `perl5/perlbrew/build` like so:

```
lrwxrwxrwx  1 darch users   12 Oct  8 14:16 perl-5.5.3 -> perl5.005_03
```

, but at that point it tries to run 5.5.3's `Configure` with options it doesn't understand.  It doesn't look to me like trying to build such old Perls with perlbrew is actually supported, for all that it does cheerfully list them.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I figured. At this point it would probably just be easier to build it manually. Oh well. :)